# Not all table names returned via my sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I use the select below, it returns only the name of one table. I have like 50 tables in my database that start with "Co" in their names.

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE 'Co%' ORDER BY name
```

It returns only 1 name "CoMyitems" which is one of the 50 tables. I would like to see all 50 names of the tables.

Comment: Leave out the `WHERE name LIKE 'Co%'` and see what the result is; are the `name`s actually `co...` or `xxx.co....` or something? It can also be a permissions issue.

Comment: Try it without the where clause - do you see all your tables in the results?

Comment: It could be some grant permissions?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query. Try and do the `select` without the `where` clause and see what you got.

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, it is recommended to use the new system catalog views in the `sys` schema - so try `select * from sys.tables` - does that show all tables? Now you can start adding `WHERE` conditions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a case error where your tables are CO.

Try:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE 'CO%' 
ORDER BY name
```

If that doesn't work it is likely a permissions issue.  Run the statement without the where clause and verify you can see the tables you want without any restrictions.

Comment: In SQL-Server, it is case insensitive

Comment: @C.J. In my experience it depends on the database coalation.

Comment: @C.J. SQL Server is only case-insensitive if the database is created with a case-insensitive collation. This is a perfectly plausible answer

Comment: @dodexahedron: If you create a database with CS collation, does that make the sysobjects also CS? I'm not sure...

Comment: Yes, because sys.objects is part of that database.  I can lab one up to verify, but I'm almost 100% certain.

Comment: @dodexahedron Doing exactly that right now ("lab one up") :-) **EDIT** Verified for SQL2012: `sysobjects` is, indeed, CS in a CS database and not CS in a CI database.

Comment: Confirmed. With case-sensitive collation, sys.objects is also case-sensitive.  Tried with two tables: `tablea` and `tableA`.  `SELECT * FROM sys.objects where name LIKE 'tablea'` only returns one of them.

Comment: The fact that you can create a `tablea` and `tableA` also kinda gives away that sysobjects is CS in that case. I know because I used `Foo` and `FOO` and came to the same conclusion :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58271/discussion-between-dodexahedron-and-robiii).

Comment: Thank you all. I will try out your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: It works now. I added the variable ($tbName) to store the name value and that worked. I don't know why though. Below is my php code:  while($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
 { 
$tbName = $row['name'];
  printf ("<tr><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$tbName);

 } Before, I had it this way: printf ("<tr><td>%s</td></tr>\n",$row[0]); and it didn't work. Thank you all again.